# Mocking autowired @Resource List

Tags: spring, junit, mockito

How can I mock a `List` of beans that are autowired by Spring in my unit tests.

So far I could not achieve result I want. Is there a way to do that?

```
@Component
public class CrmStatusChecker {

    @Resource
    private List<IsAliveEnabledComponent> components;

    ....
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CrmStatusCheckerTest {

    @Mock
    private List<IsAliveEnabledComponent> isAliveComponents;

    @InjectMocks
    private final CrmStatusChecker crmStatus = new CrmStatusChecker();;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/springockito-annotations). It allows for replacing beans in the spring context with mocks.

Another issue is that with type erasure, your `List<IsAliveEnabledComponent>` just becomes a `List<Object>`. So you have just mocked `List`. This might be why Mockito is ignoring it.

If you are loading a Spring context, I would use Springockito. Otherwise, I would create a set of mock `IsAliveEnabledComponent` instances, create a list of those and call the setter manually in your setup.

Comment: It seems that Springockito should do the trick, but its just too much trouble :) Ended up mocking IsAliveEnabledComponent and adding list manually.